# how to generate sharable link based on form input

Tags: php, facebook, forms, hyperlink, social-networking

So I'm working on a form that takes a link and outputs to a page with a custom made header by me.(similar to StumbleUpon)

What I'm having trouble with is being able to share that page on facebook or other social media. Because currently it has the same link no matter what page it is.(the link is the page I have the form action as).

I want the outputted page to be have "sharable" link. Like when I paste the link of that page on facebook, it generates thumbnails, a short description,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically, the process should be something along the lines:

```
1. Take input from the form (presumabli input type=text name=url)
2. Save that $_POST[url] to the database, and assign unique identifier to it (id, hash, uuid, ...)
3. Redirect user to visit.php?hash=assigned_hash which will display the saved page based on the hash from the database
```

That is one approach (better in my opinion). Another approach is, change form method to GET, so you will get link

```
http://yoursite/url.php?url=http...
```

Which can then be copied and pasted, but also enables users to see the link and possibly alter it and what else.

Let me know what you think

Comment: Will do as soon as i get the chance to try it out ^_^

Comment: I got the first two parts down, I took the input and assigned it to the database with an AI id and a char input, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do step 3.

Comment: Well, when user visits `visit.php?id=XX`, you query the database like `SELECT url FROM table WHERE id = XX`, and then redirect user with `header('Location: '.$url);` to the link which is saved in database.

Comment: I know how to query the database and how to redirect but how do you make the 'visit.php?id=XX" part do I have to use 'GET' for the link to interact with the code ?

Comment: I am not sure I follow?

Comment: -I know how to 'SELECT url FROM table WHERE id = XX'
-I know how to 'header('Location: '.$url);'

-I don't know how to make the 'visit.php?id=XX' page